# What conditions should be met to notice a Doppler effect on light?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, doppler-effect

What relativistic conditions should an observer meet to notice the Doppler effect on a sample light wave, and is it even possible for one?

Comment: What do you mean by "conditions"? The [relativistic doppler effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Doppler_effect) is well-known and occurs whenever there's relative motion between sources and receiver.

Comment: I mean what relative speed should an observer move with, along the source of light, to notice the Doppler effect (if it's even legitimate and, moreover, possible).

Comment: You can notice the Doppler effect in every measurement of spectral lines of atoms in a gas - the line width there is dominated by the Doppler broadening in many cases.

Comment: See  Mossbauer spectroscopy  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6ssbauer_effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you clearly ask for a detection criterion of the doppler shift on "**a** sample light wave", I have taken the liberty of assuming the following scenario. You detect light from a source, emitting light of a known wavelength (the usual case in astronomy for instance) with an instrument that is capable of measuring wavelength with an accuracy (i.e. with an uncertainty) $\Delta \lambda$.

If you want to claim that you have *detected* a redshift with a single measurement, then usually you would have to see a shift that is at least 3 times the uncertainty in your measurement. i.e. $3\Delta \lambda$ (this is a very standard criterion, corresponding to a $>99$% confidence, but you can use whatever multiplier you feel comfortable with).

A doppler shift of this size will be measurable if you are moving at a *relative* speed $v$ with respect to the source of
$$ \frac{v}{c}  >  \frac{3\Delta \lambda}{\lambda},$$
where I am assuming that $v \ll c$ in order to use the approximate doppler shift formula.

*If* your instrument measures frequency instead, then you just replace $\Delta \lambda/\lambda$ with $\Delta f/f$.

*If* you are using a radar gun (that isn't in your question, but appears to be what others think you asked) then the doppler shift is multiplied by two because the shift occurs once upon reception by the reflecting object and then again when you receive the signal again. In this case, divide the right hand side by 2.

*If* your question refers to the human eye. Then according to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision#Wavelength_and_hue_detection) you are capable of detecting wavelength shifts of $\Delta \lambda \sim 1$ nm in ideal circumstances, which with my formula yields velocities of $\sim 2250$ km/s. (But this assumes you have a stationary, identical light source to compare the colour with.)

In astronomy, doppler shift measurements are becoming accurate enough to discern relative motions of just less than 1m/s.

The precision of earth-based measurements can be higher because often you are simply comparing an outgoing signal with a reflected signal. e.g. Radar guns are good to roughly $\pm 0.4$ m/s, but [laser doppler velocimetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Doppler_velocimetry) appears to be able to detect velociites as small as 0.2mm/s. http://www.usa.canon.com/CUSA/assets/app/pdf/encoder/LaserDopplerVelocitySensor.pdf

Comment: How did you get the factor of three? The doppler shift for light sent to a received from a slow moving object $\frac{\Delta f}{f} = 2\frac v c$, which suggests that $\frac v c > \frac 1 2 \frac {\Delta f}{f}$.

Comment: @David Hammen  You misunderstand. If I have a machine/spectrograph that measures to a precision of $\Delta \lambda$, I am saying the absolute shift needs to be 3$\Delta \lambda$ before I can claim a detection. $v/c = \Delta f/f$ at low speeds - or are you talking about some radar gun type arrangement? Yes, if that *is* the scenario, you can divide my formula by two.

Comment: I don't get it. Where does the 3 come from?

Comment: @RobJeffries - (1) You posited an ability to measure wavelength to within $\Delta \lambda$. Where does the factor of three come from? (2) How do you know the rest wavelength? If it's a signal reflected back to the source, that's easy. If the source and receiver are separated, that's not so easy. (3) Oftentimes it's easier to measure frequency shift as opposed to wavelength shift by heterodyning the two signals and measuring the resultant beat frequency.

Comment: @David Hammen (1) 3 times your measurement uncertainty is a typical level at which you believe your detection of an effect. (2) I am an astronomer. Why wouldn't I know the rest wavelength? (3) What two signals? You have obviously made up some scenario that isn't part of the question. I will edit my answer to make clear what assumptions I am (not) making.

Comment: @Ben Crowell 3 times the measurement uncertainty for a significant detection.

Comment: Except the 3Δλ, which seems to be method-specific, I'm quite satisfied with the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

"Relativistic" velocities (velocities in excess of 0.1 c) are not needed. Any velocity difference will do. People use the doppler effect right here on Earth. Some sample uses:

[image]
Catching speeders.

[image]
<sub>(source: [milb.com](http://www.milb.com/assets/images/1/9/8/46291198/cuts/Yordano_Ventura_7dzk3b1g_mco9y5lo.jpg))</sub>

How fast is his fastball? (Very important at this time of year.)

[image]
Where is that tornado going?

Answer (score 0):

Your choice of the word "notice" is ill-defined. The Doppler effect holds true for all waves, at all speeds, so in that sense, you could "notice" the Doppler Effect for any wave you choose, no matter what the speed of the source or observer is (as long as there is *some* relative motion between the two.) Even as you walk across a room towards a lamp (to keep things simple, let's keep the light coherent) the light would be blue-shifted.  However, the change in apparent frequency would be so small that you would never be able to tell the shift on your own.

What you likely mean, though, is to be able to notice the effect with your own eyes without any other kind of measuring aid.  Human perception can be a tricky thing, but generally to notice the Doppler Effect in that sense, the speed of the source or observer has to be on the same order of magnitude as the wave in that medium.  The speed of light is huge ($c\approx 3 \times 10^8 m/s$) so for you to notice any apparent shift in frequency, either the source or observer should be traveling some measurable percentage of the speed of light.  This is most noticeable on cosmic scales where galaxies are usually moving away from (but in rare cases, moving towards) us at great speeds, and as a result, entire galaxies are red-shifted in the case of receding galaxies, or blue-shifted in the case of approaching galaxies.

As a semi-humorous afterthought, I've also heard the joke that cars on the highway are a perfect example of the Doppler Effect in light.  A stationary car has white headlights, but as a car drives away from you, its tail lights are red.  This is, of course, in tended to be humorous.  Highway speeds are far too slow, in the grand scheme of things, to notice a red-shift.